# Why do I use preposition at notice verb?

Tags: american-english

I have some question with following sentence.

1.Don't take too much notice of it.
2.Don't take too much notice it.

Q1. I want to know as to what difference between them?

Q2. At native English speaker, If the speaker heard like #2 sentence from someone.
How much the speaker understood(with structure)? Also How does the speaker recognized sentence like 2?

Q3. As beginner, I often used sentence like #2. 
Also Should I have to remember what verb need to preposition at all? How can I learn this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#1 is correct.  #2 is incorrect and sounds very awkward.  The important thing here is that the verb is *take*, not *notice*.  The word *Notice* can be a verb, but here it is a noun.  You could leave off the *of* if you are also omitting the thing of which notice is being taken:  *Don't take too much notice* is fine.

*...notice of it* is a compound noun structure, like *can of beans* or *time of day.*  You're defining what sort of notice you are taking (*notice **of it***)  There is an interesting discussion of this type of construction (and when it is allowed/normal) over at ELU: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131240/noun-of-noun-vs-nounnoun

Bottom line, though, is that the verb *take* isn't requiring the preposition - it is the compound noun structure.

*Take a can.*
*Take a bean can.*
*Take a can of beans.*